# Rails 4 i18n, how to translate routes where subdomain is used for the locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-i18n

I am using subdomains to determine the locale in a Rails 4 website. I have this working with a locale switcher exactly the way I want it but now I need to translate the routes and I'm not sure about the best way to proceed.

I have looked the https://github.com/kwi/i18n_routing i18n routing gem but this doesn't work with subdomains, it seems to change the path by adding /locale which is not what I need.

Other gems seem to be out of date with Rails 4.

**Edit**

Basically I want to be able to use the same view helpers but have the urls change to use whatever language is reflected by the selected sub-domain. this is just about route translation.

I have language specific templates which work and I can produce language spevific navigation templates but I would really like to not have to worry about changing erb path and url erb tags

**End edit**

A sample from routes.rb

```
scope module: 'countries', shallow: true do

  get 'south_american', to: 'south_america#index', as: :south_america
  scope module: 'south_america' do
    get 'south-america-weather', to: 'weather#index', as: :south_america_weather
    get 'south-america-gps-maps', to: 'gps#index', as: :south_america_gps
    get 'south-america-accommodation', to: 'hotels#index', as: :south_america_hotels
    get 'south-america-vacations', to: 'vacations#index', as: :south_america_vacations
    get 'south-america-facts', to: 'facts#index', as: :south_america_facts
  end
```

Using south_america_hotels_path as an example will generate a url for

> south-america-accommodation

which is great but how would I translate this so that when I am on the Spanish subdomain south_america_hotels_path will generate the following url

> hoteles-en-sudamerica

**UPDATE**

Also how would this work for a url rather than just a path so that
south_america_hotels_url will generate

> en.some_site/south-america-accommodation

and when on the spanish subdomain I would get

> es.some_site/hoteles-en-sudamerica

and so on for the different locales involved.

I am happy to use yml files for the translations for the urls or to define the additional routes in the routes.rb file, either is an option but I would prefer to define the url's in the routes.rb but I am unable to find a way to provide language specific urls for the same :as path/url option based on subdomain.

**Update and further clarification in response to previous replies.**

Changing the url's is not an option, they need to match existing url's. I just need to know how to translate them from a view helper point of view without having to change the view helpers.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Rails i18n guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html)? It explains how to use subdomains for setting the locale. Translating routes is something that Rails doesn't do out of the box; take a look at [rails-translate-routes](https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes) or [route_translator](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator) for that.

Comment: @janfoeh I am totally happy with the way I am handling the subdomains, it is just the route translation that is causing me trouble, The gems you point to are not suitable for my needs. Surely this can be done without the use of a gem

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**EDIT:**

This gem is my recommended way to do it. Supports multiple languages without reloading the routes (Which my example didn't). You have to change very few things but it's more consistent than the code below. [route translator](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator)

**Original answer (not working):**

<s>This is what have worked for me, you can try it out, in your routes for example you can put:</s>

```
AppName::Application.routes.draw do
    get "/#{I18n.t("index")}", :to => "pages#index", :as => "index"
    get "/#{I18n.t("contact")}", :to => "pages#contact", :as => "contact"
end
```

this will get you the routes in your default locale when you run the app, however in runtime, when you change your locale you need to redraw your routes in order to get the routes for the new locale.

```
I18n.locale = :es #different locale
AppName::Application.reload_routes!
```

Assuming your default_locale is `:en`, this example will take the first routes from:

```
en:
  index: "index-in-english"
  contact: "contact-in-english"
```

and when the app reload the routes, it will take the translations from your new locale, in this example from

```
es:
  index: "index-in-spanish"
  contact: "contact-in-spanish"
```

This way you it will render pages#index and pages#contact and it'll only change the route, you don't have to touch your code. Hope this helps you

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for the detailed explanation I can easily implement this and it is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, the domain should not be the only thing that determines the locale. It's so much easier if you just put the current locale into a cookie, so that the User can choose in the end!

Now to the translation-part of your question. I think you should change the way you are using the routing.

If you see the countries as resources, and the actions as a different part, you will make your life easier. The model `to_param` method can help you with that:

```
resource :country do
  get :weather, on: :member
  ...
end
```

That will result in urls like `south-america/weather` but from my perspective, that is even better in terms of readability and search engine optimization. google used to like paths a lot.

For the different translations of your paths, you could iterate over your domains and provide a translation for each segment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#translated-paths

Comment: Changing the url structure is not an option. The urls need to match urls for an existing site that is being migrated over to Rails

Comment: Also there are no resources involved.

Comment: in this case, i would use rack-rewrite to handle migration logic

Comment: It's not an option. My client wants/needs the urls the way they are. I just need to know how to translate them.

Comment: BTW, I agree with what you are saying. It's not my call.

Comment: does it have technical restrictions? if it's about SEO, redirecting old urls to the new schema with 301 redirects is a common practice.

Comment: No technical restrictions. The client has the urls they want and they want them to stay the same. I have some technical restrictions in the organisation of the controllers as I have automated breadcrumb trails and sitemap that expects a controller hierarchy hence the countries scope with shallow routes. There are over 800 pages to deal with accounting for over a thousand routes for a very busy website. Really, all I need to know is how to translate the routes. Even if I sort out redirects I will still be faced with the same problem.

Comment: Do you think this is possible to achieve?

Comment: I think that whatever you want to build, it should be possible. I just don't know enough about your problem domain to give good advise. Just start with the simplest thing possible and then move on!

Comment: The simplest thing is what I have, which is English url's, all I need to do now is convert those same path and url helpers to produce Spanish urls from the Spanish subdomain. So my navigation links and links used throughout the site will not need to be replaced with different paths in link_to erb tags. Make sense? Thank's for your persistence with this. It is appreciated. Shame I can't add multiple thank you votes

Comment: did you try iterating over all your subdomains, scripting your routes? when using proper scopes and always the same names, rails should be able to resolve all the right routes even when using the path-helpers.

Comment: I had a look at the link you supplied in your answer regarding this but wasn't sure about the implementation of your suggestion so, no, I haven't but would love to give it a try if I understood the suggestion :)

Comment: Rails routes are just code. You can load a yaml file with all the paths and translations and just iterate over them. That should work if everything is "unique" by a given scope, which you have, it's the country here.

Answer (score 1):

To translate routes in a Rails 4+ app, take a look at the [**route_translator**](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator) gem. It allows translating routes and comes with a number of configuration options, such as adding a locale section to the generated paths, or support for subdomain based app.