# Rails routes based on locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rails-i18n

I'm working on a multilingual rails app and I need the routes to be different for each locale. It's difficult to explain it like this for me, so I'll use an example:

- en: /en/pricing
- es: /es/precios

I found this answer: [Rails 4 i18n, how to translate routes where subdomain is used for the locale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469439/rails-4-i18n-how-to-translate-routes-where-subdomain-is-used-for-the-locale)

Therefore my routes.rb looks like this:

```
scope "/:locale" do            
  get "/", to: "pages#index", as: "index"
  get "/#{I18n.t("pricing")}", :to => "pages#pricing", :as => "pricing"
end
```

I'm also using `AppName::Application.reload_routes!` on app loading (application controller before_action), but just right after a locale change the rest of URI after /locale stays the same - that makes a problem when user tries to reload the page because that is non-existent any more. Other clicks are okay, with new locale URIs.

I'm thinking of a system to find out whether my current URI is the correct one and if not, redirect it there, but I think this is suboptimal. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have monkey-patched a solution for this problem. Just set a `before_action confirm_path` in the application controller just after setting the locale.

```
def confirm_path 
  current_path = Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(request.env['PATH_INFO'])
  MyApp::Application.reload_routes!
  correct_url = url_for(controller: current_path[:controller], action: current_path[:action])  
  if correct_url != request.original_url
    redirect_to correct_url, status: 301
  end
end
```

I do not really recommend this answer and I know it is not ideal. Use a gem instead as @dgilperez have mentioned. I'm posting it just in case someone's in a situation when it's too late to refactor your code.

Answer (score 3):

I've been using [rails-translate-routes](https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes) gem for this exact purpose for a while now in production sites ([Qoolife is an example you can check](https://qoolife.com)).

If you are using I18n as the translation backend, it will behave just fine. If your project happens to use [gettext](https://github.com/mutoh/gettext) as well, have a look at [my fork of the gem](https://github.com/dgilperez/rails-translate-routes/tree/emjot-stable). As an alternative, you can have a look at [route_translator](https://github.com/enriclluelles/route_translator) gem.

With any of those, the code would look quite similar:

```
# config/routes.rb
ActionDispatch::Routing::Translator.translate_from_file('config/locales/routes.yml')

# config/locales/routes.yml
en:
  routes:
    # you can leave empty locales, for example the default one
es:
  routes:
    pricing: precios
```

Then you will need to set your `locale` from the subdomain using a route constraint or in your `ApplicationController`. Have a look at [this issue](https://github.com/francesc/rails-translate-routes/issues/12) where this particular is discussed.

Comment: unfortunatelly that is not an ideal solution, it requires a gem and to rework the entire structure. Ideally `reload_routes!` should be called when user clicks on different locale. Could you suggest some hack for this? Thanks

Comment: I would definitely prefer using a well tested gem to a *hack*. I would actually be very happy to consider that a "refactor" and not a "rework" ... Also, calling ``reload_routes!`` everytime a user hits a resource ... well, that seems not only ugly and a miss-use for that method, it also requires you to do some "rework". I'd suggest you consider the gem instead.

Comment: Also, I just realized you pretend to include the locales in the route instead of subdomains. That should work out of the box with the gem.